# How do you convey unordered facts building on each other in a vertical composition?

Tags: page-layout, user-experience

I'm trying to design a website for my employer and started with the landscape/desktop layout for the section in the first image, intending to convey that it's significant that both facts are present, without any particular order to them, like two sides of a coin.

[image: Desktop side-by-side text arrangement]

I think it works satisfactorily on desktop, but when you get down to the 320px mobile width, the side-by-side arrangement would either have disgustingly small size/spacing, or be very tall, thin and unreadable.

*Is there a vertical, one-on-top-of-the-other arrangement/decoration that communicates relatedness without implying hierarchy? (this one doesn't do a good job, I think., though I'd love to be proven wrong).*

[image: Mobile arrangement, stacked, with horizontal divider]

I would try a diagonal slash through the arrangement, but I think the coders would have a fit trying to implement that on our budget.

Comment: I think your solution works. In the horizontal version, our reading direction places the left-hand point, then the right-hand one consecutively. In your vertical solution, the same order holds. Neither one really prioritizes your two points as numbering them (for example) would.

Answer (score 1):

In some similar situation I have solved it with a [jssor slider](https://www.jssor.com/).

[image]

Comment: The html <blink> mark-up used to drive viewers nuts. It became a pariah and a trait of poor web site designs and quickly fell into disuse as being mindlessly distracting. I would not encourage "noisy" site content.